# Superuser: retag-request for 64-bit, 64bit and maybe x64

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, retagging

On superuser "64-bit" and" 64bit" tags should be aliased into one or the other.

"x64" is similar, but may be a slightly different animal for some people, being specific to the mainstream AMD architecture? maybe leave that one as is? or not.

Answer (score 2):

All 64Bit and x64 tags merged into 64-Bit.

Comment: -1: x64 is a specific 64bit architecture (like SPARC), where as 64-Bit covers any of them.

Comment: Considering the SU userbase, splitting the two would be extremely dangerous as the majority of SU users will never ask questions regarding SPARC. For SF however I agree they need to be seperated.

Comment: @Diago: Also need to be separate on SO.